# Como impedir que minha aplicação java possa ser aberta duas ou mais vezes simultaneamente?

Tags: java, aplicação-desktop, runtime

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto, nele preciso impedir que o usuário possa executar a aplicação mais de uma vez ao mesmo tempo, ou seja, se a aplicação já estiver rodando ao invés de ser executada novamente ela deve informar ao usuário que já está em execução.

Comment: via API windows tem como pegar a lista de processos em execução, certamente vai ter um processo rodando com o nome da sua aplicação, então seria só pegar os processos e checar qual nome bate com a sua aplicação, se ele já estiver na lista dê um alerta e depois um exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem duas maneiras de se fazer isso, as duas maneiras tem que retornar os processos em execução para que você consiga comparar e verificar se o seu programa já esta rodando...

maneira mais fácil(sei lá, não gosto muito, mas é uma alternativa), você pode rodar um `exec` para chamar o `tasklist.exe`, se tiver em linux talvez um `ps -ax`, mas em solo windows ficaria algo assim por ex

```
try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
    BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line); 
    }
    input.close();
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

Dentro do while será mostrado cada processo rodando existente, você vai ter que organizar essa saída, eu acredito que usando o `tasklist.exe /fo csv /nh` deixe a saída em um formato mais simples para criar delimitadores, certamente você terá que tratar a saída, depois da saída tratada é só comparar, ex:

```
if("seuprograma.exe".toUpperCase().equals(line).toUpperCase())) {
                        result = true;
                        break;
            }
```

A maneira que eu acho mais interessante e que certamente seria a minha escolha é pegar os processos via API, em windows eu recomendo que utilize o [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) com o [Java Native Access](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) é possível ler o `Kernel32.dll` do windows e utilizar as [classes fundamentais da Microsoft](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Classes)

Exemplo com `JNA`:

```
public static boolean ChecarPrograma() {
    try {
        Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary(Kernel32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
        Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();
        boolean resultado = false;
        WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
        try {
            while (kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {
                if ("Meuprograma.exe".toUpperCase().equals(Native.toString(processEntry.szExeFile).toUpperCase())) {
                    resulto = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot);
        }
        ModManager.debugLogger.writeMessage("MeuPrograma.exe " + (resultado ? "Está" : "não Está") + "em execução");
        return result;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        ModManager.debugLogger.writeErrorWithException("Exceção de acesso nativo crítica: ", t);
        ModManager.debugLogger.writeError("O Mod Manager relatará que o programa não está sendo executado para continuar as operações normais.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Entendendo o que está acontecendo:

Dê uma olhada nessa parte do código aqui [`kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot), verifica na documentação do windows o que essa função faz:

```
Takes a snapshot of the specified processes, as well as the heaps, modules, and threads used by these processes.
```

tradução:

```
Tira uma captura instantânea dos processos especificados, bem como os heaps, módulos e threads usados por esses processos.
```

Agora olhe no link acima e verifique na documentação o que é dito sobre o parâmetro `TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS`:

Tradução da parte que importa:

```
Inclui todos os processo do sistema no snapshot...
```

E por fim, dentro do `While` ele está fazendo um [Process32Next](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32next), mais uma vez olhando a documentação podemos notar que essa função fica responsável por recuperar as informações sobre o próximo processo registrado em um snapshot...

Acho que é isso, escolha qual caminho acha mais interessante para o seu projeto...